# Windows 2016 Remote Desktop Services (RemoteApp) single user only limited to only two sessions - is there a way to increase this?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

I am stuck little bit on one problem. I have Windows server 2016 with RDS services installed, fully functional, CAL licenses per user installed and group policy for multiple sessions are configured.

Problem I am facing is that we need that one user can connect from more that two PCs. But as it is now max is 2. Is there a way to increase this?

Comment: Have you tried a "gpudate /force" on both the client PCs and the server? Maybe it's just a matter of slow propagation.

Comment: Yes, tried it. 100 different user can connect with out any issues. 
Maybe more precise terminology would be - Is there a way to allow for single user more that two active parallel sessions?

Comment: It's an old trick, but you never know. Can you take a look at this (https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2617/How-to-allow-multiple-RDP-sessions-for-the-single-user-in-Windows.html)? If enabled, you'd have to restart your server, which isn't the funniest thing you can do with your clothes on as a sysadmin...